# How to change the single-line comment leader in vim?

Tags: vim

For vim, the default single-line comment leader is "//". I want to change it to "// " (add a space after //). Should I change comments option? Or is there any other way to make it?

Thanks.

Comment: I am using NERD Commenter (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218). So I can change NERD_commenter.vim to make it happen.

Answer (score 8):

```
" .vimrc

" It's better to change it only for specific types of files
autocmd FileType c,cpp let b:comment_leader = '// '

" Comment a text block by selecting it in V mode and pressing \cc
noremap <silent> <leader>cc :<C-B>silent <C-E>s/^/<C-R>=escape(b:comment_leader,'\/')<CR>/<CR>:nohlsearch<CR>

" Also
autocmd FileType c,cpp setlocal comments-=:// comments+=b://
```

Comment: `" do you not think writng your whole answer as a vim comment is a bit weird?`

Comment: Some of the comments might be valueable to keep in your vimrc with the lines of code, to remember what they do and how to use them and stuff.

Comment: What does `comments+=b://` at the end do?

Comment: @echristopherson That adds the entry `b://` to the comments list, which is very similar to the entry removed by `comments-=://`, but with one significant change. It adds the "b" flag to the comment marker `//`, which tells vim that the `//` should always be followed by a blank.